# How is linear motion achieved in this automatic blackboard eraser?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, mechanisms, manufacturing-engineering, material-science

In the animation shown below what can be the mechanism used for this purpose? I know it can be achieved by using rack and pnion gear arrangement. But how are this set up arranged in classroom environment, I have no little idea. Please help me about this mechanism.
**And what can be best suitable material for this wiping action** Thanks
Video link: https://youtu.be/VB3FGRPSqsI
[image: blackboard clearner]

Comment: ROFL  If that is a board cleaner, all I can say is the engineer went lunar buggy on it.

Comment: Yes it's a board cleaner, similar prototype kink: https://youtu.be/sShy2FVXS6g

Comment: Linear motors with a bunch of erasers is not the video you have above.

Comment: I have attached the link for the video which is there in the question.

Comment: Even both the video uses same mechanism, I guess

Comment: [Auto-Clean Eraser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xwCwbKrZQc) [Minutes of Amazing: Automatic Eraser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ih0rISQA8yQ)  Shows linear motor mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

that is a scanner that converts the writing on the board into a digital file for remote sharing, and then erases the board.

These devices use either a rack-and-pinion gear arrangement with the rack running along the top edge of the board, or a flexible cable-and-pulley system with an electric motor coupled to the pulley through a set of reduction gears.

You can get an excellent idea of how the cable-and-pulley systems work by taking apart an inkjet printer and studying the print carriage transport mechanism; almost all inkjet printers use this arrangement to move the printhead across the paper surface.

Comment: Sir i think it's a blackboard cleaner, there are lots of similar prototype on YouTube like: https://youtu.be/sShy2FVXS6g

Comment: @Satya it first scans the image then cleans it - how did you miss that?

Comment: I missed it because the video clip is too short, will edit my answer.